# Can a group of sufficiently trained and armed high school seniors form an ad hoc force and defend against a battalion of militiamen?

Tags: warfare, weapons, military, military-defense

Yeah this sounds really crazy but hear me out.

So I’m working out this semi-alternate history and post-apocalyptic story that’s essentially similar to The 100, The Division, The Hunger Games trilogy, and 71: Into the Fire (dramatized but really cool and fascinating war movie set during the Korean War).

Anyway, here’s the scenario:

**The Seniors**

Let’s imagine that 215 high school seniors must attend this two week-long mock paramilitary exercise towards the end of the school year as a requirement to graduate. This mock paramilitary exercise is part of a class called Civil Defense Studies/CDS.

According to Section III of the Civil Defense Act of 2013 (signed into law by President Joe Biden), all high schoolers are required to take four whole years of Civil Defense Studies in order to graduate, with the big final being the mock paramilitary exercise. Anyway, in CDS, students are taught a variety of skills critical to the defense of DC. They’re taught everything from basic first aid, agriculture, wilderness survival, etc. all the way to how to shoot, assemble/disassemble, clean, maintain, and care for the M16A5 (standard service rifle of the United States Garrison, which is basically the US military but consolidated into a single unified branch), basic guerrilla tactics and strategies, military land navigation, rudimentary and extremely basic military skills, etc. This is to give high schoolers skills that may contribute to the defense of the District of Columbia should say, the Virginia Federation ever break the armistice and invade DC.

So these 215 high school seniors are also all pretty physically fit (given the state of things) and have the basic necessary survival and paramilitary skills. A couple of the seniors (like around 20) are also joining the US Garrison and are cadets who are part of the Military Readiness Program (MILREP), a Garrison-run and organized program that gives those who are enlisting into the Garrison physical fitness training as well as very basic skills that are more in-depth than what’s taught in CDS and are much more military-oriented in order to help prepare them for Military Recruit Training. 
All of these seniors are also apprentices and students of a particular trade of their choosing. After order was reestablished in DC, the old pre-Black Flu education system was overhauled and a much more trade-focused system that honed in on practical applications was implemented. Many seniors are either in some sort of science field (chemists, engineers, mechanics, etc.) while others are focused on farming/agriculture, construction, defense/security, etc.

**Defense Plans**

This mock military exercise takes place in Camp Rapidan located near the Shenandoah National Park. [This is the defense plan for the defense of the camp](Imgur (https://imgur.com/gallery/0SGxbIY)). The big block with two tiny triangles, an X in a circle, and two lines of X below it is the main camp where the bulk of the seniors will be. The big triangles on top of the mountains represent two M777 howitzers that are part of the camp’s arsenal (they’re for training). The three smaller triangles are mortars. The five boxes with Xs in them are major observation posts set up in abandoned houses. The five lines with Xs running through them are major defensive lines with sandbags, MG nests, foxholes, towers, etc. while the three large individual Xs w/ no line running through them are hidden independent defensive positions.

**Critical Assets and Resources**

There are 15 pickup trucks at Camp Rapidan and these allow the seniors to move around fairly quickly. The pickup trucks are used to ferry around seniors, weapons, ammo, supplies, etc. and can also be dedicated mobile weapons platforms if needed (e.g. attaching a mortar or machine gun).

There are also three HMMWVs that are a great asset since they can fill in as a mobile heavy support platform in case of a firefight.

As for food and water, the Rapidan River offers fish to catch and eat as well as fresh, clean water. There are also a ton of wild animals like deer and squirrels around the area so hunting happens, supplying the camp with a decent amount of fresh meat. Camp Rapidan itself is also stocked full of food and water. In the chow hall, there is enough food to feed everyone for two months straight along with enough MREs to keep everyone fed for another two months. Despite this, rationing has taken place and MREs are only given out if the fresh food stock is beginning to get low. There is also a lot of farmland south of the camp where some crops are grown and harvested. It also helps that the camp has a medium-sized pond where drinking water and some fish can be found.

**Weaponry**

Everyone has an M16A5 rifle that’s issued from the camp armory and everyone has a baseline total ammo count of 45 rounds (everyone has two magazines, one w/20 rounds and the other w/25 rounds). Seniors who shot a 90 to 100 on the annual Student Marksmanship Exam are given extra magazines and ammo if needed since they’re better shots. Because there are only 15,000 5.56 NATO rounds in total, everyone needs to save as much ammo as possible because in a firefight, ammo runs out pretty quickly depending on how crazy things get.

There is also a decent amount of heavy support weapons; there are five M2 Browning machine guns, with two at the camp itself while the other three are dispersed at each defensive lines. There are also four Soltam K6 M120 mortars, three of which are located at where the three small triangles on the map are while the last one is located in camp.

Some of the more scientifically-focused seniors will create a couple of mines and IEDs made out of old tin cans, spare ammo cans, etc. There are also real grenades but the actual grenades are reserved for if/when SHTF and the invading militia is about to enter Camp Graves Mill. Because of this, crude rudimentary grenades will have to do.

The main prize that the seniors have are two M777 howitzers. These are the best kept secrets of the camp and are the most vital assets in the entire camp due to the immense amount of fire support that they can deliver. One will be overlooking the valley area outside of camp while the other will be put on top of the hill overlooking Camp Graves Mill (again, the M777 positions are indicated on the map as the big red triangles).

(You might be thinking “how do a bunch of high school seniors know how to operate mortars and artillery”. The reason why some of them know how to operate them is because they’re either taught how to during class or they have/had family members in the Garrison who taught them how to operate it for whatever reason. I know, pretty unrealistic but just play along).

**Unit Organization**

The 215 seniors are all led by Mason Sato, a cadet in the Military Readiness Program as well as a member of both the Washington Senior High Orienteering Team and Washington Senior High Simulated Combat Team.

The 215 seniors will be split into two individual smaller companies (Company A will have 105 seniors while Company B will have 110 seniors).

Company A will be further split into three platoons (1st, 2nd, and 3rd Platoons) who will each have 35 seniors. Company A will be tasked with defending the two lines leading into Camp Graves Mill as well as being responsible for the defense of Camp Graves Mill itself. If possible, individual squads and sections from Company A can and will be sent to help support Company B.

Company B on the other hand is also split into three platoons (4th, 5th, and 6th Platoons). 4th and 5th Platoons will have 36 seniors each while 6th Platoon will have 38 seniors. Because Company B is slightly larger than Company A, Company B will cover the three defensive lines in the valley, with 5th and 6th Platoons stationed at the first defensive line facing south while 4th Platoon will split into two sections and take up the rear lines.

**Opposition Force: The 9th Militia Infantry Battalion**

The 9th Militia Infantry Battalion (9th MIB) is a part of the Virginia Federation Army Militia (VFAM). The 9th MIB is composed of 600 part-time militiamen led by Lieutenant Colonel John Del Mara, a former Virginia Federation Army officer who suffered an injury during the Potomac War before the signing of the Potomac Armistice, forcing him to medically retire from the regular Army and transfer to the Militia in order to continue his military career. 
The 9th MIB is a fresh and newly-raised unit, meaning that they possess no combat experience on a unit-level, save for the couple of old veteran soldiers in the battalion like LtCol Del Mara.

The VFA Militia as a whole is pretty much comprised of poorly trained and equipped units that are at times lazy and unprofessional with military conduct (it doesn’t help that low morale is prevalent throughout the ranks). A lot of these militiamen are either conscripted criminals, unqualified to join the Federation Army, or were forced out of the regular Army and had to transfer to the Militia. Militiamen at times lack unity, with some wearing a mishmash of random uniform items and others even bring different weapons to the fight (Specialist Joe might have an AR-15 while Private John has an AK-74 and Sergeant Jay has an old M16A3 with Corporal Jack having a Remington Model 870 shotgun. All of whom are in the same unit). The only real sense of uniformity and military professionalism that the Militia has is with the officers and even then it’s kind of iffy at times. 
There also exists a sort of classism in the Militia; officers usually have the much nicer and better gear and weapons while the enlisted would be lucky to even see one or two of those gear in their squad or platoon (e.g. pretty much all officers are equipped with body armor and/or plate carrier of some type while the vast majority of the enlisted only have either their uniform itself or, if they’re lucky, a combat vest).

Because Virginian military doctrine states that all critical heavy weapon support is crucial to the regular Army first and foremost, this leaves the Militia with little (if any) heavy weapons capable of delivering a massive amount of fire support. At best there might be like one or two light mortars connected with the HQ company of the battalion but that’s about it. Everyone else is pretty much purely infantry.

So, with all of this in mind, would my ad hoc company of high school seniors be able to effectively defend against an entire battalion of militiaman?

Comment: Can you cut short on the text? It's a huge wall you have here...

Comment: Obviously yes, warfare is too complex to say no here. This is the opposite of what the average question is like here. You seem to be actually building a world and put a lot of effort into it. However, warfare is complex. Anything can be done. I think your question isn't asked right. This is just my guess, but I think you don't know how a fight works. You have build your world, but now that you've got a lot of details (too many, your question is almost unreadable), you don't know how to do the battle though. Is that correct? With that in mind, maybe you'd like to focus and ask it differently?

Comment: Clarifying: this is a military exercise.  Pretend fight.  All of the specifics on weapons boil down to: pretend weapons.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Willk no. I should’ve made myself more clear. At first, yes, it’s a simple military exercise but after a series of unfortunate events, it becomes a very real battle and fight to the death.

Comment: Do the seniors have specialists?  People who can operate communications systems?  People who can operate counter-battery fire direction systems?  Forward observers?

Comment: You seem to be asking "Can an attacker with a 3:1 advantage in infantry, but no surprise, succeed in a frontal attack against prepared positions when both sides have modern weapons and the defender has an advantage in heavy weapons and fire support?" Generally not.

Comment: @user535733 siege tactics, cut their supply lines and wait.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi except that the seniors have natural resources like wild game, fresh water, etc. at their disposal. Yeah it’s impossible that they’ll always get a good hunt but they can hunt every now and then to stay in the fight.

Comment: *"Militiamen at times lack unity, with some wearing a mishmash of random uniform items and others even bring different weapons to the fight":* this is utterly unbelievable to this European. When I was a lad in the Socialist Republic of Romania, and we actually had a militia ("Patriotic Guards"), the militia had its own reserve depots of uniforms and weapons. An infantry battalion would have uniform armament (usually AK-47s) including one [PK machine gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PK_machine_gun) per company (six of them in the example given in the question). Maybe Virginia is different.

Comment: @user69268 if you let them enough ground, so they will. If the perimeter is close enough. bah-bye wild game and wandering outside the position you defend.

Comment: @AlexP to be fair, do keep in mind that my story/scenario takes place in a post-apocalyptic scenario and the Virginia Federation Army Militia is much less cared for compared to the regular Federation Army (which is extremely well cared for). The militiamen are literally just guys who were handed a set of utility/combat uniform, given two weeks of light training, and they may or may not be issued a rifle w/sufficient rounds in the first place.

Comment: @user69268 I think that's a tough oint of this question.  You specify how much ammo  high school stutdents have, but are very hazy on ammo for the other side.

Comment: @AlexP LOL. the capitalistic US used the resources more efficiently, to the point of tacitly admitting the militias are some sort of folklore traditions, old-wives tale (even if they keep this written lore somewhere for the show) - "let them live their self-deception if this can make us more money. In fact, we may even get to create more of it, let's invent Marvel"

Comment: *"They may or may not be issued a rifle w/sufficient rounds in the first place":* then why bother to call them a militia? What is purpose of the state to raise those utterly depraved and ineffective units in the first place? Not to mention that I find it completely unbelievable that a modern country which is not absolutely dirt-poor doesn't have *ample* reserves of man-portable weapons, enough to equip all male population of military age. The army *never ever* throws away stuff. I would be ready to wager a small sum that the Romanian army still has a lot of bolt-action ZB vz.98/22 rifles...

Comment: 1: Please cut out about 30% of your text. I really don't care about some random specific names and their entire backstory.

2: As much detail as there is for the seniors it's very sparse for the militia.

3: What are the conditions around the battle? Does the militia have to attack along that corridor? can they just flank them out and attack from somewhere else/all sides?

4: My current impression is more "How the heck could the militia possibly win this?"

Comment: from what i can get from the context and comment seems like supply is the most vulnerable, even if the wild animal wont go far away despite many people goes into the forest, i can imagine they can do inhuman action considering your militia is a bunch of criminal, like  just burn the entire forest and farmland while throw or launch poop or other excrement into the lake to contaminate it or using the farmer as hostage.

Comment: oh yeah also blocking or create a dam in the rapidan river, i believe the militia number would be enough to achieve this, though i am not good with math, and considering what you describe seems like the senior task is more focus on defense right ?

Comment: on the other hand are surrender acceptable ? since its more likely this militia will just surrender right away anyway, but if surrender is not an option or get decline or get death treatment for surrender then i assume thats the kind of strategy they do, they have number advantage to do this simultaneously while your senior is limited in numbers.